# How to define $B_{\omega}$ where $B_{n+1}=\{\text{limits of functions in $B_n$\}}$ and $B_0=\{\text{continuous real functions}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

This is Ex. $6.1.3$ in Stillwell's "Real Numbers," with the heading

Classes of Functions Obtained as Limits

I would appreciate help:

Defining $B_{\omega}$ where $B_{n+1}=\{\text{limits of functions in $B_n$\}}$ and $B_0=${continuous real functions}

It is supposed that each $B_{n+1}$ has members not in  $B_n$.

(I really don't like to say that I don't know what to do and to not show any work, yet that is the case.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe two (slightly) different conventions have been used for this.  The one I prefer is $B_\omega=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$.  The other makes $B_\omega$ the set of limits of functions in $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$ (which would be $B_{\omega+1}$ under my preferred convention).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you would please elaborate a bit as to what some of the $B_n$s look like beyond $B_1$, Regards,

Comment: @Andrew I don't really have much intuition for the $B_n$'s.  There's a little information available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function and a google search for, say, "Baire class 2" or "Baire class 3" might get you more insight, but I don't think there's any characterization of these classes that's more helpful than the definition.

Comment: A good reference for the first couple of levels is [MR0655599 (83j:26001)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=655599). 
van Rooij, A. C. M.; Schikhof, W. H.
**A second course on real functions**. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge-New York, 1982. xiii+200 pp. ISBN: 0-521-23944-3; 0-521-28361-2.

Comment: A reference going beyond the one above is [MR1321597 (96e:03057)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1321597). Kechris, Alexander S. **Classical descriptive set theory**. 
Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 156. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1995. xviii+402 pp. ISBN: 0-387-94374-9.

Comment: See also [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/414514-simple-examples-of-baire-class-one-functions/) for examples of level 1 functions and [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/414514-examples-of-baire-class-two-functions/) for level 2 examples. Already level 3 seems near hopeless.